# Using pictures (JPEG) from web as symbol in MapServer 7 mapfile?

Tags: symbology, mapserver, mapfile, web

Is it possible to configure the mapfile so, that it shows for every point on the map a different picture from the web recognized by an id?

Comment: Every feature in a layer will have it's own identifier, so the question is I think more about attaching some image to every feature in your database.  My feeling is that it should be doable either through use of ```SYMBOL``` (probably OK for small datasets) , or ```STYLEITEM```

Comment: You should convert your comment to an answer and accept it.  This will help others with the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a sollution to my problem: You can use an URL for the SYMBOL. We have the URL with the specific image in our database. In the mapfile we just use then the name of the attribute with the URL for the SYMBOL in the mapfile. See: [mapserver docu](http://mapserver.org/fr/mapfile/style.html)